# Read bytes from .bin file

Tags: vb.net, hex

Pardon my lack of knowledge, that is why I am here-

I am trying to verify the first 2 bytes of a .bin file with button2. The .bin is loaded via OpenFileDialog1 into Text1.text when button1 is clicked.
I want to make sure the first 2 bytes of the .bin are "ff 4f" which is what they are when I open the file in a hex editor.
I have tried a couple of different ways of doing this and have had no luck. Below is the most recent attempt. Feel free to suggest a new way. And thank you for your guidance.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim data = New Byte(9) {}
    Dim actualRead As Integer

    Using fs As New FileStream(Text1.Text, FileMode.Open)
        fs.Position = 0

        actualRead = 2

        Do
            actualRead += fs.Read(data, actualRead, 10 - actualRead)
        Loop While actualRead <> 10 AndAlso fs.Position < fs.Length
        TextBox2.Text = (actualRead)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If File.Exists(Text1.Text) Then
        Dim bytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(Text1.Text)
        ' First two bytes are in bytes(0) and bytes(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note, this can blow up if your file is over 2GB. But it will definitely do what you need. Also, I added the OpenFileDialog code as a visual aid for the file we are manipulating.

Comment: The .bin file is 16.5MB so I should be safe, however when I applied this it appears to only open another OFD prompt. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you can remove the OpenFileDialog code. If you already have the path to the file, that's what you need to pass into File.ReadAllBytes(). File.ReadAllBytes() returns a byte array containing the byte content of the file. You can then use the index of that byte array to get the first and second bytes.

Comment: @WilliamHenson I have modified the code so that it uses the text from Text1 as the file path.

Comment: This returned the bytes for me, so I converted to hex and verified and instead of converting in the code I simply added : If bytes(0) = 255 And bytes(1) = 79 Then MessageBox.Show("Magic-Verified")

Comment: Perfect! Converting to hex is unnecessary if you know the decimal value of what you're looking for. Hex makes reading bytes easier for developers.